# how limit on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox

I would like to select maximum two check-box after after clicking on that it will show message.I had implement code it working when i am not used array when i am using array in check box it will not work.my code is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function chkcontrol(j) {
  var total=0;
  for(var i=0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++){
  if(document.form1.ckb[i].checked){
  total =total +1;}
  if(total > 3){
  alert("Please Select only three") 
  document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false ;
  return false;
  }
  }
  }
  </script>


  <form name=form1 method=post action=check.php>
  <table width=''250''align=center>
  <tr bgcolor=''#f1f1f1'' ><td >
  <input type=checkbox name=ckb value=1 onclick='chkcontrol(0)';></td><td >PHP</td></tr>
  <tr bgcolor=''#ffffff'' ><td >
  <input type=checkbox name=ckb value=2 onclick='chkcontrol(1)';></td><td >Perl</td></tr>
  <tr bgcolor=''#f1f1f1'' ><td >
  <input type=checkbox name=ckb value=3 onclick='chkcontrol(2)';></td><td >MySQL</td></tr>
  <tr bgcolor=''#ffffff'' ><td >
  <input type=checkbox name=ckb value=4 onclick='chkcontrol(3)';></td><td >ASP</td></tr>
  <tr bgcolor=''#f1f1f1'' ><td >
  <input type=checkbox name=ckb value=5 onclick='chkcontrol(4)';> 
  </td><td >JavaScript</td></tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

Above code is working but when i am using

```
   <input type=checkbox name=ckb[] value=4 onclick='chkcontrol(3)';></td><td >ASP</td></tr>
```

Its not working

```
  I would like to store multiple value in array of php 

   <?php
   print_r($_POST['ckb']);
   ?>
```

Comment: It does not have the name '`ckb[]`' in your original code.

Comment: its example but when i am change name service(original) then also it produce same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***jsFiddle demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/daqqozz5/)

P.S, don't use inline JS (it's hardly maintainable; try always to keep JS compact); do like:

```
<input type=checkbox name=ckb[] value=1>
```

Than the JS would be:

```
var formCkb = document.form1["ckb[]"];

for(var i=0; i<formCkb.length; i++){
  formCkb[i].addEventListener("change", chkcontrol, false);
}

function chkcontrol() {
  var tot = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<formCkb.length; i++) tot += formCkb[i].checked;
  if(tot > 3){
      alert("Please Select only three"); 
      return this.checked = false ;
  }
}
```

<sub>Following the amazing UI suggestion by @PacMan:</sub>

### Here's how to disable the remaining checkboxes

...without the annoying alert:

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/daqqozz5/1/)**

```
var formCkb = document.form1["ckb[]"];

for (var i=0; i<formCkb.length; i++) {
    formCkb[i].addEventListener("change", chkcontrol, false);
}

function chkcontrol() {
    var tot=0, notChkd=[];
    for (var i=0; i<formCkb.length; i++) {
       if (formCkb[i].checked) tot += 1;
       else notChkd.push( formCkb[i] ); 
    }
    for(var i=0; i<notChkd.length; i++) notChkd[i].disabled = tot>=3;
}
```

Above `notChkd` Array is used to store all the other *non-checked* elements.
Once the `tot` counter exits the loop, you can flag the *remaining* checkboxes as `disabled` by using `tot>=3` as boolean.

Comment: I encourage you, instead of using the alert, to disable the remaining checkboxes if two checkboxes are already 'checked'. Alternatively, the submit button could become disabled if more than two checkboxes are checked - OR - a `<span> (message) </span>` could be shown/hidden above the list of checkboxes.

Comment: @PacMan-- +1!! great UI tip! I totally agree.

Comment: i need also disable remaining check-box please help me.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this:

```
 function chkcontrol(j) {
  var total=0;
  for(var i=0; i < document.form1["ckb[]"].length; i++){
  if(document.form1["ckb[]"][i].checked){
  total =total +1;}
  if(total > 3){
  alert("Please Select only three") 
  document.form1["ckb[]"][j].checked = false ;
  return false;
  }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adopt a more clear implementation like this

```
<input type = checkbox name = 'ckb' value = 1 onclick = 'chkcontrol(this)'> 

function chkcontrol(obj) {
    var checkedLen = 0, checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName(obj.name);
    for(var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if(checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            checkedLen++;
        }
        if(checkedLen > 3) {
            alert("Please Select only three") ;
            obj.checked = false;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm sorry that I only know about C.
But there must be something calls timer. Which it will keep on running the code that you want it to run. You can keep on checkin number of check box that is checked

Comment: It's a very bad idea to keep an *Interval* running on your page without control. It's also unnecessary due to other *event* driven techniques. Also, your answer is very low quality, it comments rather than properly answer the question with valuable info.

Comment: A timer is not really a bad idea though. A timer allows you keep on running the code that you want it to run.